# Ruby Unpermitted parameter: :event_log for nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an `event_log` that I'm trying to update the status on when a form for `event` has been submitted. When I try and pass it in the form, it creates the `event` but it shows `Unpermitted parameter: :event_log` in the console. Relevant code is below, If any additional code is needed please let me know.

**_event_accept_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :event, url: events_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :title, :value => @event_logs.event.title %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :description, :value => @event_logs.event.description %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :start_time, :value => @event_logs.event.start_time %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :end_time, :value => @event_logs.event.end_time %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => @event_logs.user_id %>

  <%= f.fields_for @event_logs do |event_log| %>
    <%= event_log.hidden_field :status, :value => :event_accept %> 
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Accept', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :title, :description, :start_time, :end_time, :user_id

  has_many  :event_logs, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_logs

end
```

**event_controller.rb**
...

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time, :user_id, :sender_id, { event_logs_attributes: [:id, :status] })
end
```

**event_log_controller.rb**

```
def show
    @event = Event.new 
    @event_logs = EventLog.find(params[:id])
    @invitee = User.find(@event_logs.invitee_id)
end
```

**Error on Console**

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-27 18:37:25 -0600
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters {"utf8"=> "✓"," authenticity_token" =>"BRqfTU2Rya8yKS// 
Tp2zp6HV6RSD1b82w+5ng/ lzv15Hs/q35lDxNZtxy0yXBaSyPzKeExJpYjBV/DfmwfnK3w==", 
"event"=>{"user_id"=>"4", "title"=>"another 2", "description"=>"ihihi", 
"start_time"=>"2019-01-22 01:41:00 UTC", "end_time"=>"2019-01-22 03:41:00 UTC", 
"sender_id"=>"2", "event_log"=>{"status"=>"event_accept"}}, "commit"=>"Accept"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: :event_log
```

The form is actually being called in the `event_log` show view:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <%= render "events/event_accept_form" %>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the curly braces...`event_logs_attributes: [:id, :status]`

Comment: The same error occurs. ‘Unperimmited Paramater’

Comment: Can you put your error stacktrace on the question?

Comment: @JavierMenéndezRizo I added the error

Comment: kindly add the controller method as well.

Comment: @GaganGupta Added the controller method

Comment: I guess I've found the error: 
in your controller method try changing `@event_logs = EventLog.find(params[:id])` to `@event_logs = EventLog.where(params[:id])`

Comment: @GaganGupta When i try that it gives the same error `Unpermitted parameter: :event_log`

Comment: @GaganGupta Do you know of another way to update a status besides using the form?

Comment: @GaganGupta Also, If I add this line `<%= f.hidden_field @event_logs.status, :value => @event_logs.event_accept! %>` it updates the status but it does it without clicking the accept button

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the way that the form is been generated(Notice that the unpermitted parameter is event_log and you should be sending event_logs_attributes).

Since is a event form I suppose that you are sending an @event instance variable to the view

```
<%= form_for :event, url: events_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :title, :value => @event.title %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :description, :value => @event.description %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :start_time, :value => @event.start_time %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :end_time, :value => @event.end_time %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => @event.user_id %>

  <%= f.fields_for :event_logs, @event_log do |event_log| %>
    <%= event_log.hidden_field :status, :value => :event_accept %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Accept', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time, :user_id, :sender_id, event_logs_attributes: [:id, :status])
end

def show
    @event_log = EventLog.find(params[:id])
    @event = @event_log.event
    @invitee = User.find(@event_log.invitee_id)
end
```

Comment: its giving the same error. Sorry I should of added Its being called from `event_log` view. I added more detail in the edit.

Comment: Your @event_logs should be singular(@event_log) since is just an event_log, I updated the answer with a fix on your controller

Comment: On your case you just need to show in the form your specific event_log, I updated the form for that

Comment: I tried that and it gives me the same error `Unpermitted parameter: :event_logs`

Comment: Could it be because the form is creating a new `Event` and I'm trying to push an update to that `EventLog` to update the enum status?

Comment: If I add this line `<%= f.hidden_field @event_logs.status, :value => @event_logs.event_accept! %>` it updates the status but it does it without clicking the accept button.